# Can't adjust screen brightness if laptop isn't charging on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I recently updated Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L440.

If the charger is plugged in, everything works fine. If the charger isn't plugged in, I can't use Fn+F2 or Fn+F3 to change the brightness. I can still go to my settings and change the brightness.

I installed all the Windows updates and Lenovo updates. I tried uninstalling and installing my monitor's driver. Everything worked fine in Windows 8.1.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Try reinstalling Hotkey Features Integration drivers.

Comment: your PC could be in power saver mode?/?